# Save Clipboard Dev Express GridControl

Tags: c#, gridcontrol

I am implementing copy and paste in a table. The problem is that when pasting, I need to change the clipboard before pasting. I do it in the `GridControl_PastingFromClipboard(object sender, PastingFromClipboardEventArgs e)` method. With this approach, the old clipboard is lost but I need to return the old buffer after pasting. How do I do this?

I tried to save the buffer, but I didn't find any event triggered after insertion to return it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I would suggest you take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps include some of the code you have tried in your question. :) See: [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that you need to add 'e.Handled = true' to the beginning of the method and in the end
'table.OnPaste();
Clipboard.SetText(_clipboardOld);'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).